# Creating a Pull Request in Azure sentinel Repository

Tags: azure, azure-sentinel

For contributing to the github repository i.e. making a PR in the **Azure sentinel Reposiroty:** *https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel* is it necessary to become a Microsoft partner or I can directly contribute without doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The README of that repository contains a [contributing](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel#contributing) section:

> **Contributing**
>
> This project welcomes contributions and suggestions. Most contributions require you to agree to a Contributor License Agreement (CLA) declaring that you have the right to, and actually do, grant us the rights to use your contribution. For details, visit https://cla.microsoft.com.
>
> When you submit a pull request, a CLA-bot will automatically determine whether you need to provide a CLA and decorate the PR appropriately (e.g., label, comment). Simply follow the instructions provided by the bot. You will only need to do this once across all repos using our CLA.
>
> This project has adopted the Microsoft Open Source Code of Conduct. For more information see the Code of Conduct FAQ or contact opencode@microsoft.com with any additional questions or comments.
>
> For information on how to contribute, refer to the "how to contribute" guide on the project's wiki.

It is not necessary to be a Microsoft partner to contribute. You simply need to accept Microsoft's [CLA](https://cla.opensource.microsoft.com/) (Contributor License Agreement). Send a PR and follow the instructions of the bot there, it will tell you how to proceed.

Comment: After my PR is approved and displayed on the github repository, how much time approximately take to reflect my deployment on Microsoft Azure Platform publicly?

Comment: @YatharthDholakia That depends on how they've set up their CI/CD. I don't know where you might find that information. Good luck.